# Phonegap: Object xx has no method 'exec' at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I developed a tiny module in Android. When using the debug- or run method in Eclipse to test the app on my "real" device, everything works flawlessly.
Using Eclipse (Kepler), PhoneGap 3.1 and Android API 10
But when I sign, export, install and run the app, I see the following error in the debugger once the plugin is called:

> file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 863 : Uncaught TypeError:
>   Object org.apache.cordova.al@41ae5438 has no method 'exec'
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object org.apache.cordova.al@41ae2400 has no
>   method 'exec' at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js

I am waiting for the deviceready with a deferred object:

```
var def_deviceready = $.Deferred();
document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, false);

function deviceready(){
    def_deviceready.resolve();
}
function dbaccess(query, arg, callback) {
    var dbaccess = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/dbaccess");
    $.when(def_deviceready).done(dbaccess.getData(query, arg, callback));
};
```

dbaccess.js:

```
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/dbaccess", function (require, exports, module) {
    var exec = require("cordova/exec");
    module.exports = {
            getData: function (query, arg, callback) {
                exec(callback, function(){ callback('callbackerror')}, "DBAccess", query, arg);
            }
    };
});
```

DBAccess.java:

```
public class DBAccess extends CordovaPlugin {

    HashMap<String, SQLiteDatabase> dbmap;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public DBAccess() {
        dbmap = new HashMap<String, SQLiteDatabase>();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, String arg, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        Log.v("info", "This is what we got here: action=\'" + action +"\', arg=\'"+ arg +"\'.");
        if (action != null) {
            String Result = getData(action, arg);
            this.echo(Result, callbackContext);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
.....
.....
```

...and also the config.xml contains:

```
<feature name="DBAccess">
  <param name="android-package" value="com.phonegap.plugin.dbAccess.DBAccess"/>
</feature>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the whole project again, thanks to the comment of Vicky (I had the dbaccess.js included...).

I found that for some reason, AppLaud configured my App to run with PhoneGap 3.0, but it was being exported with 2.9, *and* a different config.xml - hence the inclusion for my module wasn't there at all. I could not figure out where or how the different version/xml file was configured/located in.

So I ended up creating a whole new project, copied my relevant files into the according folders, and now I am up and running!

Answer (score 3):

your script is not able to include dbaccess.js try to add it forcefully in head tag. thats why its not able to exec the method